# What is the difference between freeipa and openldap

Tags: openldap, freeipa

What is the difference between openldap and freeipa. Aren’t they same? What is the main work of them and how do they are interconnected or they are separate thing?

Answer (score 4):

- [OpenLDAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenLDAP) is just an open-source LDAP server.
- [FreeIPA](https://www.freeipa.org/page/About) is a product built on top of well known Open Source components such as: LDAP,  389 Directory Server, MIT Kerberos, NTP, DNS ..etc. It is an open-source alternate to Windows Active Directory. also it is the upstream project for [Red Hat Identity Manager](https://access.redhat.com/products/identity-management)